# Unable to import a file and text filed from same HTML form

Tags: django

I need to import a file and text(field) from same html form.  But I am getting the error:

```
Unable to upload file. MultiValueDictKeyError('name',)
```

**new.html**

```
 <form action="{% url "upload2" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="file" name="xlfile">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

**veiw.py**

```
def upload2(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, "homepage/new.html")
    try:
        myfile = request.FILES['xlfile']
        cname = request.GET['name']
        print(cname)
        return HttpResponse('ok')
     except Exception as e:
         logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))
         messages.error(request,"Unable to upload file. "+repr(e))
```

**Error**

```
Unable to upload file. MultiValueDictKeyError('name',)

Internal Server Error: /upload2

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/csdj/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "/home/csdj/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

ValueError: The view homepage.views.upload2 didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Try this : cname = request.POST.get('name')

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with uploading a file. As the error clearly shows, it is happening on the `name` field; because you are trying to get it form `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`.

Really, though, you should be using a Django form.